# Trying to solve a 'TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int''

Tags: python, typeerror

```
import sys

def displayGreeting():
     print("\nThe Wizard will see you now."
                                      + "\n"
                                      + "\nOK, let's get started\n")


def askQuestions():
    counter = 0
    
    name = input("What's your name? ")
    
    age = checkAge()
    
    numOfQuestions = checkNumofQuestions()
    

    for counter in range(1, numOfQuestions + 1):
         
         question = input("\nWhat's your question?")

         if question.strip() == "":
              print("You should enter a question")
              continue


         if question.strip().lower() == 'bye':
              break
         else:
              message = processQuestion(counter, question)
              
              print(message)
              
              print("\nNo more questions for you!")
              
              print("Stop bothering the Wizard!")
          
                
def checkNumofQuestions():
    numOfQuestions = input("\n\nHow many Questions do you want to ask the wizard? ")
    
    if numOfQuestions.isnumeric():
         numOfQuestions = int(str(numOfQuestions))
         
         numOfQuestions += 1
         
         print("I am giving you a bonus. You can ask", numOfQuestions, "questions!")
    else:
         print("Warning: ", numofQuestions, "is not a Valid number! I am changing it to 5")

         numOfQuestions = 5

         return numOfQuestions

def checkAge():
    while True:
        age = input("What is your age? ")

        if age.isnumeric():
             
            age = int(age)
            
            if age < 10 or age > 80:
                 print("please enter a valid age between 10 and 80")
            elif age > 30 and age < 50:
                 print("these are prime earning years")
                 break
            else:
                 print("you are a good age to play this game")
                 break
        else:
            print("Please enter a valid integer for your age")
            return age
            
def processQuestion(counter, question):

    if question.startswith("Who"):
        message = "Who, Who... isn't that a sound an owl makes?"
    elif question.startswith("What"):
        message = "What is the meaning of life?"
    elif question.startswith('How'):
            message = "How now, brown cow?" 
    else:
        message = "I don't know"
        message = str(counter) + ". The Wizard answers: " + message + "?"
        return message
       
def main():
     print("Assignment 4\n")

     print("* * The Wizard Game * *")

     playGame = input("Do you want to talk to the Wizard? (Yes or No) ")

     playGame = playGame.strip()

     if playGame.lower() == "yes":
          displayGreeting()
          
          askQuestions()
     else:
        print("The Wizard wants you to go away now!")
        print("\n\nEND OF PROGRAM")


main()
```

I don't even know where to start with this. I tried some things but it didn't help at all. I'm still left with the error.

Here is the full traceback error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "filename.py", line 107, in <module>
    main()
  File "filename.py", line 101, in main
    askQuestions()
  File "filename.py", line 19, in askQuestions
    for counter in range(1, numOfQuestions + 1):
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: Please run the code and copy and paste the full error message including line numbers and traceback (you can edit our your name if it appears)

Comment: Also we dont even know whats running because all we are given is two functions.

Comment: Okay, so the error message shows you the line of code `for counter in range(1, numOfQuestions + 1):`, yes? So, let's apply some reasoning to that. The error message says there is a problem with a `+`, right? Where's the `+` on that line? `numOfQuestions + 1`, right? The message says the problem has to do with adding `'NoneType' and 'int'`, yes? So - `1` clearly is the `int`, which means `numOfQuestions` is the `NoneType` - makes sense? So the next two questions: 1. do you know what a `NoneType` is? 2. How are you expecting `numOfQuestions` to get its value? Did you check that that code works?

Comment: If you don't already know what `NoneType` means, the way to answer that is with a search engine, or by referring back to whatever tutorial you are using to learn Python. For the second question, you answer that by looking backwards through the code.  On the previous line, we have `numOfQuestions = checkNumofQuestions()`, so that tells use something must have gone wrong in the `checkNumofQuestions` function. **That** is "where to start with this". For future reference, please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. Also, welcome to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't returning `numOfQuestions` in the first branch of your if-else in `checkNumOfQuestions`. In Python if a function doesn't explicitly return a value it returns `None`. So when you get to `range(1, numOfQuestions +1)`, `numOfQuestions` is `None`. In python, attempting to add two incompatible types generally gives you a `TypeError`, specifying the types of the two operands, as you got here.